# Preventing the volume HUD from appearing with MPMusicPlayerController, is it acceptable?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpvolumeview

My issue is the HUD that accompanies a change in the `MPMusicPlayerController`'s `volume` property. Whilst there is a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868457/applicationmusicplayer-volume-notification), I want to know if it is acceptable by Apple to hide the `MPVolumeView` to prevent the HUD from showing?

And on another note, if I choose not to use the `MPVolumeView` class, will the user still have the option to play audio from the app on an AirPlay device via the multi-tasking bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Submitted my app and it was acceptable. It seems that it is OK with Apple to use the described method.