# Adjust iOS volume without the overlay and with the AirPlay icon

Tags: ios, airplay

My app needs to fade some music in, starting from 0 and slowing going up to the iPod volume setting. When I do this, the stock Apple volume adjust screen shows up. I followed the directions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868457/applicationmusicplayer-volume-notification) and create my own MPVolumeView.

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
[self addSubview: volumeView];
```

This almost works perfectly, I do not see the system volume UI, which is good, but what I *do see* now is the AirPlay icon in the upper left hand corner. How can I make that go away?

(And yes, perhaps it would be better if the icon were there but sometimes the visual designer wins...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [`showsRouteButton`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to `NO`.

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
volumeView.showsRouteButton = NO;
[self addSubview: volumeView];
```

But be aware this will also hide any bluetooth route available and the user can still select airplay via the quickswitch dock.