# Customize iOS Volume HUD in a Unity3D Game

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am currently working on a Unity3D iOS game.I want to override the default Volume View in iOS and implement a custom UI control like in Snapchat and Instagram.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: you want c# unity code or swift code ?

Comment: Preferably c# unity code

Answer (score 0):

### What you need is low level access to your native iOS application in order to use swift code to disable the volume HUD.

I cannot explain how to do this better than this https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5/blob/master/README.md

Follow the instructions carefully until you are able to setup swift in unity.

Here is a good page on disabling the volume HUD in swift: [Hide device Volume HUD view while adjusitng volume with MPVolumeView slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444376/hide-device-volume-hud-view-while-adjusitng-volume-with-mpvolumeview-slider)

Hope this helps.