# Swift: Volume button long press and release

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation

I am working on a camera app that requires that whenever a volume button is long pressed, it should take a burst shot just like in the native iPhone camera app.
I am unable to get the event of a long press.
Any kind of help would be appreciated how can I get the long press event of the volume button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no available API for this event. You can only detect volume change by observing [`outputVolume`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616533-outputvolume) or with a [`SystemVolumeDidChange`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249775/system-volume-change-observer-not-working-on-ios-15) notification (private API).

The behaviour you are describing that can be find in the system Camera app is something only apple can do with their private APIs.

Edit: Your best bet would be to monitor the frequency of volume change events and based on that you could trigger the "burst" that lasts as long as the events are coming.

Comment: I agree with you. But there should be something available that snapchat app uses to capture this event.

Comment: If I had to guess they are monitoring the frequency of volume change events and based on that they are triggering the "burst" that lasts as long as the events are coming.